# matplotlib GridSpec indexing yields unexpected results

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a subplot arrangement that I am trying to tame with `matplotlib.gridspec`. Following the example [HERE](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html), I came up with the following for my plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

f = plt.figure()

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:,:])

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs2[:,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs2[:,1])

plt.show()
```

Where I am expecting to get three subplots, I get this:

[image]

How do I get the following result?:

[image]

Comment: What output do you want? Where do you want your plots positioned?

Comment: I want three subplots in one row. [gs1[0], gs2[0], gs2[1]]. The above is just [gs2[0], gs2[1]].

Comment: I've updated my question with an illustration of what I'm describing as my desired result. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if whoever down-voted my post would leave an comment as to why, so I may attempt to correct whatever is somehow lacking in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout) example (copied almost verbatim):

```
fig = plt.figure()

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.33, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:,:])

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
gs2.update(left=0.38, right=0.98, wspace=0.05)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:,0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:,1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: That is the same example I was working from, and is the same as my provided example with the exception of the updated params... strange. Do you know why it is necessary to do the update? I found another example that uses embedded gridspecs that I was able to get working without the update part: https://stoqs.googlecode.com/hg/contrib/analysis/trajectory_biplots.py

Comment: @shootingstars because the `update` call is the line the actually does what you want.....

Comment: Is the update call not just setting spacing for the elements? Why would the first be omitted if spacing is not declared?

Comment: @chzhu why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @chzhu, I found your answer very useful, as this isn't directly described in the documentation. tcaswell, do you have a suggestion for ways that I might improve my question, as I feel it is valid given that the docs say that "Optionally, the subplot layout parameters (e.g., left, right, etc.) can be tuned.", where they are in fact required to be set in order to get correct output. Thanks for the help.